# Как создать файл (размер: 0 байт), при удалении которого освободится 100МБ на диске?

Tags: windows

Как создать файл (размер: 0 байт), при удалении которого освободится 100МБ на диске?

Comment: @Vitalts, да это отличный вопрос, а вместе с ответом они сразу ставят на место кучу "экспертов".

Comment: Не меняйте вопрос, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 22):

В Windows под размером файла обычно понимается размер основного потока данных - именно он отображается как "размер" в проводнике (и в остальных утилитах для работы с диском).

Но кроме основного потока данных к файлу можно дописать несколько дополнительных потоков, размер данных в которых не будет включатся в общий "размер" файла. Называется эта фича [Alternate Data Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404(v=vs.85).aspx). Раньше она использовалась для совместимости с маками. Сейчас используется для хранения метаданных - например, свойств картинок - тех самых "снято, выдержка, размер" и прочих, которые можно задать в свойствах файла.

Вобщем, достаточно простого вызова CreateFile с суффиксом ":streamname" в имени файла - и можно писать на диск "неучтенные" данные. Вот пример, создающий файл с отображаемым размером в 0 байт, при удалении которого освобождается 100 мегабайт:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    HANDLE hFile, hStream;
    DWORD dwRet;

    hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\temp\\testfile",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        0,
        NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Cannot open testfile\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
        // WriteFile(hFile, "This is testfile", 16, &dwRet, NULL);
    }

    hStream = CreateFile(L"C:\\temp\\testfile:stream",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        0,
        NULL);
    if (hStream == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Cannot open testfile:stream\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            WriteFile(hStream, "1234567890", 10, &dwRet, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Его будет выдавать ненулевой Size On Disk, отображаемый в свойствах файла в проводнике - но этот размер и для обычных файлов может не совпадать с Size.

Во всех остальных местах размер файла будет отображаться как 0.

Comment: Но ведь не учет альтернативных данных используемым программным обеспечением при определении размера файла это не есть неиспользуемое дисковое пространство. Файл все же будет занимать на диске эти 100 Мб.

Comment: соглашусь с @Vitalts вы все таки создаете не пустой файл, хоть и данные находятся в дополнительном потоке:) но все же это плюс

Comment: @Vitalts да, но в терминологии Windows/WinApi размер файла - это размер основного потока данных. то, что к файлу прицеплен багаж в 100 мегабайт - на размер файла не влияет (но влияет на место на диске). Например, имя файла точно так же хранится в стриме с типом ::$FILE_NAME. Но при этом почти никто не согласится, что переименование файла меняет его размер (хотя очевидно, что более длинное имя занимает на диске больше места) :)

Comment: @PashaPash, не могу согласится. Копирование только основного потока данных на другой носитель в данном случае сделает файл не читаемым. Это сравнимо с созданием сим линка на другом носителе. Для создания копии без потерь данных нужно скопировать и багаж в 100 Mb. Так или иначе, ваш ответ очень достоен и заслужил свои плюсы. Чего не скажешь о вопросе...

Comment: Альтернативный способ создания такого файла с применением PowerShell v3+: `Set-Content -Path FileName.txt -Stream StreamName -Value ('a'*(100mb-2))`.

Comment: @PetSerAl о, спасибо за вариант - на C# прямой работы со стримами нет, и я подумал что на PS аналога тоже не будет.

Comment: Вариант создания из командной строки: `fsutil file createnew file.dat:hidden 100000000` (впрочем, тут будет не 100 Мб, а 95 Мб).

Comment: В Linux подобное тоже возможно (начать можно с [man xattr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html)), но размер (обычно 4К)  дополнительных данных ограничен...